# Обход всех экземпляров класса (в цикле) в С++

Tags: ооп, c++

Здравствуйте!
Имеется класс:

```
Class MyClass {...};
```

делаем десять его экземпляров

```
MyClass _my_new_class1;
MyClass _my_new_class2;...
MyClass _my_new_class10;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно в цикле перебрать все экземпляры ?

Comment: > MyClass _my_new_class2;
> ...
> MyClass _my_new_class10;

См. [китайский код](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#K.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.B9.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Положить в массив и перебрать в массиве.

Answer (score 3):

- объявить массив экземпляров класса
- создать список как статический член этого класса и в конструкторе добавлять каждый экземпляр в этот список

Answer (score 3):

Как уже было сказано, создать массив  (или какой-нибудь контейнер из STL, лучше всего  для данной задачи, думаю, подойдет vector) с этими объектами. Либо создать массив (контейнер) **указателей на объекты** и по ним обходить экземпляры.